# Google Charts not accepting my JSON

Tags: php, sql, json, mysqli

I want to use google charts with JSON.

This is the file that makes my JSON file  from my php database:

```
 <?php
    //open connection to mysql db
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","register") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));



    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));



    //create an array
    $emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }



header('Content-Type: application/json');
    //write to json file
    $fp = fopen('users.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($emparray));
    fclose($fp);




//close the db connection
   mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

My JSON OUTPUT is:

```
[{
    "userID": "1",
    "userName": "admin",
    "userLast": "admin",
    "userDegree": "HBO",
    "userOrganization": "TRM",
    "userIndustry": "TRM",
    "userAddressone": "asd 1",
    "userAddresstwo": "asd1",
    "userCity": "",
    "userState": "",
    "userZip": "",
    "userCountry": "",
    "userPass": "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055",
    "userPhone": "0",
    "userEmail": "dion.jongmans@trmoncology.com",
    "userAssistinfo": "",
    "userStatus": "Y",
    "userCreated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "tokenCode": "d33164cb6de8ee9471a34ece95d91abb"
}, {
    "userID": "22",
    "userName": "a",
    "userLast": "Bernard",
    "userDegree": "",
    "userOrganization": "",
    "userIndustry": "",
    "userAddressone": "",
    "userAddresstwo": "",
    "userCity": "",
    "userState": "",
    "userZip": "",
    "userCountry": "",
    "userPass": "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055",
    "userPhone": "0",
    "userEmail": "a@admin.com",
    "userAssistinfo": "",
    "userStatus": "Y",
    "userCreated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "tokenCode": "2d123af96e8de9dcfea549cedbd3ef3e"
}, {
    "userID": "23",
    "userName": "b",
    "userLast": "Jansen",
    "userDegree": "",
    "userOrganization": "",
    "userIndustry": "",
    "userAddressone": "",
    "userAddresstwo": "",
    "userCity": "",
    "userState": "",
    "userZip": "",
    "userCountry": "",
    "userPass": "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055",
    "userPhone": "0",
    "userEmail": "b@admin.com",
    "userAssistinfo": "",
    "userStatus": "Y",
    "userCreated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "tokenCode": "2d123af96e8de9dcfea549cedbd3ef3e"
}, {
    "userID": "24",
    "userName": "c",
    "userLast": "Vermeer",
    "userDegree": "",
    "userOrganization": "",
    "userIndustry": "",
    "userAddressone": "",
    "userAddresstwo": "",
    "userCity": "",
    "userState": "",
    "userZip": "",
    "userCountry": "",
    "userPass": "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055",
    "userPhone": "0",
    "userEmail": "c@admin.com",
    "userAssistinfo": "",
    "userStatus": "Y",
    "userCreated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "tokenCode": "2d123af96e8de9dcfea549cedbd3ef3e"
}, {
    "userID": "25",
    "userName": "d",
    "userLast": "van Vliet",
    "userDegree": "",
    "userOrganization": "",
    "userIndustry": "",
    "userAddressone": "",
    "userAddresstwo": "",
    "userCity": "",
    "userState": "",
    "userZip": "",
    "userCountry": "",
    "userPass": "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055",
    "userPhone": "0",
    "userEmail": "d@admin.com",
    "userAssistinfo": "",
    "userStatus": "Y",
    "userCreated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "tokenCode": "2d123af96e8de9dcfea549cedbd3ef3e"
}, {
    "userID": "26",
    "userName": "e",
    "userLast": "Petersen",
    "userDegree": "",
    "userOrganization": "",
    "userIndustry": "",
    "userAddressone": "",
    "userAddresstwo": "",
    "userCity": "",
    "userState": "",
    "userZip": "",
    "userCountry": "",
    "userPass": "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055",
    "userPhone": "0",
    "userEmail": "e@admin.com",
    "userAssistinfo": "",
    "userStatus": "Y",
    "userCreated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "tokenCode": "2d123af96e8de9dcfea549cedbd3ef3e"
}, {
    "userID": "27",
    "userName": "f",
    "userLast": "Gaartsen",
    "userDegree": "",
    "userOrganization": "",
    "userIndustry": "",
    "userAddressone": "",
    "userAddresstwo": "",
    "userCity": "",
    "userState": "",
    "userZip": "",
    "userCountry": "",
    "userPass": "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055",
    "userPhone": "0",
    "userEmail": "f@admin.com",
    "userAssistinfo": "",
    "userStatus": "Y",
    "userCreated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "tokenCode": "2d123af96e8de9dcfea549cedbd3ef3e"
}, {
    "userID": "28",
    "userName": "g",
    "userLast": "Klompenboer",
    "userDegree": "",
    "userOrganization": "",
    "userIndustry": "",
    "userAddressone": "",
    "userAddresstwo": "",
    "userCity": "",
    "userState": "",
    "userZip": "",
    "userCountry": "",
    "userPass": "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055",
    "userPhone": "0",
    "userEmail": "g@admin.com",
    "userAssistinfo": "",
    "userStatus": "Y",
    "userCreated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "tokenCode": "2d123af96e8de9dcfea549cedbd3ef3e"
}, {
    "userID": "29",
    "userName": "h",
    "userLast": "de Jong",
    "userDegree": "",
    "userOrganization": "",
    "userIndustry": "",
    "userAddressone": "",
    "userAddresstwo": "",
    "userCity": "",
    "userState": "",
    "userZip": "",
    "userCountry": "",
    "userPass": "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055",
    "userPhone": "0",
    "userEmail": "h@admin.com",
    "userAssistinfo": "",
    "userStatus": "Y",
    "userCreated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "tokenCode": "2d123af96e8de9dcfea549cedbd3ef3e"
}, {
    "userID": "30",
    "userName": "i",
    "userLast": "",
    "userDegree": "",
    "userOrganization": "",
    "userIndustry": "",
    "userAddressone": "",
    "userAddresstwo": "",
    "userCity": "",
    "userState": "",
    "userZip": "",
    "userCountry": "",
    "userPass": "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055",
    "userPhone": "0",
    "userEmail": "i@admin.com",
    "userAssistinfo": "",
    "userStatus": "Y",
    "userCreated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "tokenCode": "2d123af96e8de9dcfea549cedbd3ef3e"
}, {
    "userID": "31",
    "userName": "j",
    "userLast": "",
    "userDegree": "",
    "userOrganization": "",
    "userIndustry": "",
    "userAddressone": "",
    "userAddresstwo": "",
    "userCity": "",
    "userState": "",
    "userZip": "",
    "userCountry": "",
    "userPass": "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055",
    "userPhone": "0",
    "userEmail": "j@admin.com",
    "userAssistinfo": "",
    "userStatus": "Y",
    "userCreated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "tokenCode": "2d123af96e8de9dcfea549cedbd3ef3e"
}, {
    "userID": "60",
    "userName": "Henk",
    "userLast": "Vermeer",
    "userDegree": "dfg",
    "userOrganization": "TRM",
    "userIndustry": "dfg",
    "userAddressone": "Parkdreef 123",
    "userAddresstwo": "Mozartlaan 438",
    "userCity": "",
    "userState": "",
    "userZip": "",
    "userCountry": "",
    "userPass": "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055",
    "userPhone": "0",
    "userEmail": "fds@fds.com",
    "userAssistinfo": "",
    "userStatus": "Y",
    "userCreated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "tokenCode": "2dfc96090d0580c77052ea730ca641ec"
}, {
    "userID": "61",
    "userName": "dion",
    "userLast": "sdff",
    "userDegree": "sdfsdf",
    "userOrganization": "sdfsd",
    "userIndustry": "h",
    "userAddressone": "fdsgxchvjngfcbvd",
    "userAddresstwo": "nhgjmkhmg",
    "userCity": "",
    "userState": "",
    "userZip": "",
    "userCountry": "",
    "userPass": "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055",
    "userPhone": "0",
    "userEmail": "7@7.com",
    "userAssistinfo": "",
    "userStatus": "Y",
    "userCreated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "tokenCode": "a8224f3750dd0fa465f5592b2c8b7691"
}, {
    "userID": "62",
    "userName": "asdasdsad",
    "userLast": "asdasdasdsd",
    "userDegree": "asdasdasda",
    "userOrganization": "sdasdasdasd",
    "userIndustry": "asdasdasdas",
    "userAddressone": "dasdasdas",
    "userAddresstwo": "dasdas",
    "userCity": "",
    "userState": "",
    "userZip": "",
    "userCountry": "",
    "userPass": "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055",
    "userPhone": "0",
    "userEmail": "a@3.com",
    "userAssistinfo": "",
    "userStatus": "Y",
    "userCreated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "tokenCode": "3158097d42a06f3619a4f65d7332e9ac"
}, {
    "userID": "63",
    "userName": "piet",
    "userLast": "molema",
    "userDegree": "sdfmaf",
    "userOrganization": "jnbfkj",
    "userIndustry": "asdasd",
    "userAddressone": "kjb",
    "userAddresstwo": "jb",
    "userCity": "",
    "userState": "",
    "userZip": "",
    "userCountry": "",
    "userPass": "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055",
    "userPhone": "0",
    "userEmail": "piet@piet.nl",
    "userAssistinfo": "",
    "userStatus": "Y",
    "userCreated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "tokenCode": "8470034e78689fbfdf02a243b2e5791e"
}, {
    "userID": "64",
    "userName": "wim",
    "userLast": "piet",
    "userDegree": "sdfnb",
    "userOrganization": "ubhi",
    "userIndustry": "biu",
    "userAddressone": "buikb",
    "userAddresstwo": "iukb",
    "userCity": "",
    "userState": "",
    "userZip": "",
    "userCountry": "",
    "userPass": "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055",
    "userPhone": "0",
    "userEmail": "qw@qw.com",
    "userAssistinfo": "",
    "userStatus": "Y",
    "userCreated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "tokenCode": "a4a48ab579a555b02fb73fa35ca19eca"
}, {
    "userID": "65",
    "userName": "henk",
    "userLast": "skdfn",
    "userDegree": "kjb",
    "userOrganization": "kj",
    "userIndustry": "nkj",
    "userAddressone": "nkj",
    "userAddresstwo": "n",
    "userCity": "",
    "userState": "",
    "userZip": "",
    "userCountry": "",
    "userPass": "81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055",
    "userPhone": "0",
    "userEmail": "m@m.com",
    "userAssistinfo": "",
    "userStatus": "Y",
    "userCreated": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "tokenCode": "a22bfc97426704ae0894882242a14016"
}]
```

But Google is saying this:

> Table has no columns

This is what i use to display the Chart:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
        google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
          var jsonData = $.ajax({
              url: "getData.php",
              dataType:"json",
              async: false
              }).responseText;

          // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, {width: 800, height: 400});
        }

        </script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Regarding Google documentation you must cave `cols` and `rows` objects in your JSON: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam

Comment: so i cannot automate my database to be a JSOn to use it in google charts?

Comment: No, you can, but yo must build proper JSON object when you fetch the data from your database.